# Does calling object-functions on a valuetype cause auto boxing

Tags: c#, autoboxing

In C#, does calling object functions, like Equals() and ToString(), on a valuetype mean that the compiler will do autoboxing to perform the operation. Eg. will autoboxing occur in the following code?

```
int x=2;
int y=7;
bool isEqual = x.Equals(y);
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

```
    static void DoIt()
    {
        int x = 2;
        int y = 7;
        bool isEqual = x.Equals(y);
        Console.WriteLine(isEqual);
    }
```

Will become:

```
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldc.i4.7
  IL_0004:  stloc.1
  IL_0005:  ldloca.s   x
  IL_0007:  ldloc.1
  IL_0008:  call       instance bool [mscorlib]System.Int32::Equals(int32)
  IL_000d:  stloc.2
  IL_000e:  ldloc.2
  IL_000f:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(bool)
```

There are no `box` IL opcodes present, so no boxing occurs.

As you can see it calls [Int32.Equals(Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf6tw08e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that does not require any boxing - it accepts non boxed Int32 struct as parameter. There is also [Int32.Equals(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de3wwa8z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - this one will demand boxing.

Answer (score 1):

If a type implements `IEquatable<T>` then the better overload resolution will chosen, and by better i mean the more specific. In this case, `int` overrides [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf6tw08e(v=vs.110).aspx), so no boxing will occur. If the interface isn't implemented, it will use `object.Equals`

From the C# spec:

> 7.4.2.2 Better function member
>
> Given an argument list A with a set of argument types {A1, A2, ..., AN} and two applicable function members MP and MQ with parameter types {P1, P2, ..., PN} and {Q1, Q2, ..., QN}, MP is defined to be a better function member than MQ if:
>
> 1. for each argument, the implicit conversion from AX to PX is not worse than the implicit conversion from AX to QX, and
> 2. for at least one argument, the conversion from AX to PX is better than the conversion from AX to QX.
>
> When performing this evaluation, if MP or MQ is applicable in its expanded form, then PX or QX refers to a parameter in the expanded form of the parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

Not in this case, because int implements `IEquatable<int>` and it is `IEquatable<int>`'s Equals that is called here, not Object's

But normally, yes.